# Understanding what data Stripe needs for a Vue and Laravel project

Tags: laravel, vue.js, stripe-payments, laravel-cashier

I am using vue-stripe and trying to setup a way to do one time purchases. I am doing a token request and it generates the token below when I enter the cc number date and cvc.

```
card:
    address_city: null
    address_country: null
    address_line1: null
    address_line1_check: null
    address_line2: null
    address_state: null
    address_zip: "42424"
    address_zip_check: "unchecked"
    brand: "Visa"
    country: "US"
    cvc_check: "unchecked"
    dynamic_last4: null
    exp_month: 4
    exp_year: 2024
    funding: "credit"
    id: "card_1IHHP9Jcu3r8UW8rqiLydyLZ"
    last4: "4242"
    name: null
    object: "card"
    tokenization_method: null
    __proto__: Object
client_ip: "137.187.202.50"
created: 1612481911
id: "tok_1IHHP9Jcu3r8UW8r81KS1HBH"
livemode: false
object: "token"
type: "card"
used: false
```

I was hoping I could take this token and give it to Laravel Cashier to complete the charge. In my controller I tried

```
$stripeCharge = auth()->user()->charge( 100, $request->card);
```

but it gave me an error

```
Invalid string: {:id=>"card_1IHHP9Jcu3r8UW8rqiLydyLZ", :object=>"card", :address_zip=>"42424", :address_zip_check=>"unchecked", :brand=>"Visa", :country=>"US", :cvc_check=>"unchecked", :exp_month=>"4", :exp_year=>"2024", :funding=>"credit", :last4=>"4242"}"
```

so instead I tried to use

```
$stripeCharge = auth()->user()->charge( 100, $request->id);
```

but it said

```
A token may not be passed in as a PaymentMethod. Instead, use payment_method_data with type=card and card[token]=tok_1IHHSfJcu3r8UW8rsTWenxiT.
```

So I tried

```
axios.post('/purchase', {
                    payment_method_data: {
                        card: {
                            token: token.id
                        },
                    }
                })
```

but that gives me the error

```
message: "You cannot confirm this PaymentIntent because it's missing a payment method. You can either update the PaymentIntent with a payment method and then confirm it again, or confirm it again directly with a payment method."
```

I feel like I am close but just not understanding what Stripe wants and what Laravel is sending when I do a charge. I would love any help!

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a Payment Method in Vue, not a token: https://stripe.com/docs/js/payment_methods/create_payment_method

Comment: I see, ok I asked the https://vuestripe.com/ plugin developers if there was a way to generate the create payment instead of the token. What is the difference between a token and a payment method?

Comment: Basically this: https://stripe.com/docs/payments/payment-intents/migration